# How to Display ListData() in CDetailView in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Suppose I have a code of CDetailView as shown in below

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'title',             
        'owner.name',       
        'description:html',  
        array(               
            'label'=>'City',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'', // ??? How to insert here ListData function that it will display list of different cities
        ),
    ),
));
```

Now in above code I want to insert the list of cities which is coming in list Data array.

```
$list = CHtml::listData($model->city, "city_id", "cities");
```

If i keep `$list` in `print_r()` . It gives out as in below.

```
Array ( [1] => London [2] => Paris [3] => New York )
```

Any Help Will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    array(               
        'label'=>'City',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>implode('<br />', $list),
        'type' => 'raw',
    ),
```

Answer (score 3):

If its not working then you can try this

```
'label'=>'City',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>array($model,'createListFunction'),
```

and then in your model class create a function with name `createListFunction`
like

```
public function createListFunction($data,$row)
{
//in this way you can access the corresponding attribute
$myTitle=$data->title;
// and finally you can return whatever you want to 
return CHtml::listData($model->city, "city_id", "cities");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Value` should have value for the column. So you have to use `filter` as below.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'title',             
        'owner.name',       
        'description:html',  
        array(               
            'label'=>'City',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>$data->city_id,
            'filter'=>CHtml::listData($model->city, "city_id", "cities")

        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: When i use 'value'=>$data->city_id, it is giving an undefined error that is $data, Second if i take 'value'=>$model->city_id, it will print just id number, but i do not need the id number i was need the value against that number.

Comment: So, to print the name of the city, you have to fetch city name in your model itself. For this, you have to define a variable in your model to store city_name and fetch city name in your query with alias name of `city_name`. Then you can directly call the city name as `$data->city_name`